# How to set a dynamic value for a json array in Karate

Tags: arrays, json, karate

i have a json file, which needs uniq values for each post request. uniqId = '55555'. for all the uniq ids i need to pass same uniqId. so far i was able to only set for only the endtoEndid. unable to set for invoiceNum and txnValue. Please help. so far i have done following:

- eval req = {"endtoEndid":"",
  "prgrmId":"2344",
  "invoices": [ { "invoiceNum":""}],
  "currency":5.99,
  "txnRefs": [ { "txnId":"name", "txnValue":""},{ "txnId":"state", "txnValue":"illinois"}]}
- eval req['endtoEndId'] = 'endtoEnd' + uniqId. (successfull)
- eval req.invoices['invoiceNum'] = 'invoice' + uniqId (not successful)
- eval req['txnRefs.txnValue]'] = 'txn' + uniqId (not successful)
  And request req

then i tried splitting:

- def reqInvoices = req.invoices
- def reqTxnRefs = req.txnRefs[0]
- eval reqInvoices['invoiceNum'] = 'invoice' + uniqId (not successful)
- eval reqTxnRefs['txnValue'] = 'txn' + uniqId (not successful)
  And request req

i need following result:

{"endtoEndid":"endToEndIduniqId",
 "prgrmId":"2344",
  "invoices": [ { "invoiceNum":"invoiceuniqId"}],
"currency":5.99,
"txnRefs": [ { "txnId":"name", "txnValue":"txnuniqId"},{ "txnId":"state", "txnValue":"illinois"}]}

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the latest version or 0.9.6.RC3.

Setting JSON is much easier now, you don't need any `eval` or `set`.

Example:

```
* def foo = {}
* foo.bar = 'baz'
* def random = function(){ return java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis() + '' }
* foo.ban = random()
* print foo
```

Which gives:

```
{
  "bar": "baz",
  "ban": "1591756622099"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response Peter, i have upgraded to 0.9.6.RC3 version, but now i'm not able to run any of my classes with RunWith(Karate.class) nor KarateOptions(). Is there any other work around for above issue?

Comment: Can i just set invoiceNum  value inside of the json file  like:

Comment: @NaryZhan no one else has reported this, so follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: I was able to set the value inside json file, so issue is resolved. thank you..