# In Karate, can I update a value for one of the fields in a Request payload (JSON format) automatically?

Tags: karate

**In Karate, can I update a value for one of the fields in a Request payload (JSON format) automatically?**

I am working on the following scenario - 
1. Submit a POST request to create an object. A Request payload (JSON format) is used.
2. Query DB to verify that this object is created. Each object creation generates a unique ID.
3. Submit another POST request to delete this object created in Step 1. A seperate request payload (JSON format) is used.

**PROBLEM -** 
How do I automatically update the request payload to delete this object? The only thing that needs to be updated in this payload is the ID field with ID's value which I will grab from the DB (step 2). Basically, all but the ID field values in Delete payload remains the same. I need this ID to update during the run time...Any ideas?

Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is easy in Karate. I suggest you read the documentation. The ["hello world" example](https://github.com/intuit/karate#hello-world) itself shows how to use a value coming back from the response.

This example shows how to get values from a database using [Java interop](https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java): [`dogs.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/dogs/dogs.feature)

And here is how you update any JSON, JS-style: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62294932/143475

Instead of asking a broad question like this, I suggest you create a real example, and ask a specific question only if you get stuck.